# Hide form action url in post method

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have this code below and i want to insert it in new script

```html
<?php
session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$username = "#";
$password = "#"; 
$dbname = "#";

$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ;
$time = time();
$waktu = date("G:i:s",time());
//database connect
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

 mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cookies` (
`ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`time` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`waktu` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ip`)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
) 
");

function get_html($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
    }
$token = $_SESSION['token'];

if($token){
 $graph_url ="http://example.com?user=" . $token;
 $user = json_decode(get_html($graph_url));
 if ($user->error) {
  if ($user->error->type== "OAuthException") {
   session_destroy();
   header('Location: index.php?info=403');
   }
  }
 }
 else{
 header('Location: index.php');
 }
 $result = mysql_query("
      SELECT * FROM cookie WHERE ip = '$ip'");
 if($result){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $times = $row;
   }
 $timer = time()- $times['time'];
 $countdown = 900 - $timer;
 }; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $token = $_SESSION['token'];
           if(!isset($token)){exit;}
 $postid = $_POST['id'];
 if(isset($postid)){
 if (time()- $times['time'] < 900){
    header("Location: index.php?info=404");
 }
 else{
 
 mysql_query("REPLACE INTO cookie (ip,time,waktu) VALUES ( '$ip','$time','$waktu')");
 $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/secure.php'); 
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$postid");
 $hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
    if (strpos($hasil,'GAGAL') !== false) {
  echo 'Done';
   }else{
        //header("Location: index.php");
        header("Location: index.php?info=401");
 }
 }
 }else{
 header("Location: index.php");
 };
}else{
$go ="hello";
}

 
 $urlSplitted = explode('?fbid=', $_GET['url']); 
 $fbid = $urlSplitted[1];
 
?>
```

And next i have new script dashboard having code below:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
 header("location:index.php");
}

 $fbid = '7676767676';

?>

<form action="" method="post" class="form-wrapper cf">
 Id Is: <font color="red"><strong><?php echo $fbid; ?></strong></font>
<input name="id" value="<?php echo $fbid; ?>" type="hidden">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Now i want to use that secure.php as hidden that no one can see that file in form action and when i send form then it automatically sends data to secure.php 
 I dont need any database to save data and no 900second timer, I am unable to edit this as simple i can.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Obligatory warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please consider using parameterised queries.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I dont need any security if its possible than answer please!

Comment: You need to simplify your question, I think, as you appear to be asking "how can I submit content to a URL without the end user being able to see that URL" (which isn't possible). Can you describe the problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You cannot hide what the browser is doing (like what URL it is posting what data to) from users.

Comment: You can sort of hide the .php location by some "proxy" page that will redirect your request. You could write a .php script that will take your request, plus a keyword telling it where to send the data, which then looks up your target .php based on that keyword.

Comment: @SukhChain As a developer, you should never assume you "don't need any security". Your question is about security, and the fact that you're asking for a way to implement a level of security that isn't possible indicates that you need a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

PHP code is useless for your question.

To obfuscate action url you could use some javascript to set attribute only on submit. Here you can see a dumb example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gprygB

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(this).attr("action", "realAction");
});
```

Thanks to this you could also use some crypt/uglify library to hide the realAction inside js file.

Comment: How does this stop the user simply enabling debug tools and reading the URL as the browser calls it?

Comment: Http is not a magic protocol. You cannot make everything hidden. Expert users always could retrieve urls they are calling

Comment: It won't prevent individual users inspecting the code but presumably it will mitigate form spam.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to create a 3rd page, call it: `NotSecure.php`.

So in your form: `<form action="NotSecure.php" method="post" class="form-wrapper cf">`, user will see only `NotSecure.php`. `NotSecure.php` will communicate with `Secure.php`, and return a response after.

Notice that `Secure.php` stays visible only for `NotSecure.php`, and your user never knows about `Secure.php` (which is what you're looking for :) ).

example for `NotSecure.php`:

```
<?php
/* init params for forwarding the post request to a page visible
   only to myself
*/ 
$url = "Secure.php";
$postBodyAsAssociativeArray = array();
// getting all POST params from the page that submited the form
$postBodyAsAssociativeArray['param1name'] = $_POST['param1name'];
$postBodyAsAssociativeArray['param2name'] = $_POST['param2name'];

// use "post" function, to post data to "Secure.php"
$result = post($url, $postBodyAsAssociativeArray);  
// print the "Secure.php" response.
echo $result;

/* use PHP CURL method to post an HTTP request */  
function post($url, $postBodyAsAssociativeArray)
{
    if(empty($url))
    {
        return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
    }

    // encode associative array to a string, in order to post it in body's
    // request
    $body = json_encode ( $postBodyAsAssociativeArray );

    /* CURL configuration shit */
    //init post object and options
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // invoke the CURL post
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    // return the post response
    return $server_output;
}
```

Comment: Okay so what should notsecure.php contains?

Comment: In this way (having a "proxy service") you however expose easily backend service to users in the same way

Comment: @SukhChain : iv'e added the  `notsecure.php` content. please tell me if that is what you're looking for...

Comment: I don't really get the point. In this way I cannot know the secure.php url but, indirectly, I can act as if I knew it because unsecure.php proxies it

Comment: ask @SukhChain why does he need to hide `secure.php`. for example: you grant user access to `unsecure.php` but not for `secure.php` (say `secure.php` is a diferent server, which serves multiple sites for vlidating a username&password, and returning an access token, (like: login with your facebook/google acount) need careful security, etc. ... . another example is implementing a `bridge pattern` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), so each programmer can work on "his files" independently from the other

Comment: @CaptainCrunch actually my that file contains senstive data and it can be used from other sites if someone see action url , and your example doesnot worked for me :(

Comment: @CaptainCrunch is this possible that only user logged in to my site can post the form other wise it redirects to my index if posted from other server?

Comment: @Sukh Chain you're mixing 2 things. if you want to block some paths for some users or all in your server, read about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess , section: "Common usage" (htaccess is for an Apache server, but you each server has a way to do those kind of staff). after that, i'll recommend having specified folders for secure pages. you'll want to restrict users from getting to these folders, and allowing them to get to the non-secure folders. than, put your `notsecure.php` and `secure.php` accordingly.