# How can I hide the form action with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, action

My current code looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php" role="form" id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="forms" name="forms" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="valid" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
            <button type="button" id="stop" class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to hide the form action "test.php" file like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="" role="form" id="form">
```

Comment: If you hide it,  how does your form know where to send the data to?

Comment: What you can do is implement some kind of CSRF prevention class.

Comment: `document.getElementById("form").setAttribute("action", "");`? Is that what you want?

Comment: No matter how you see this,  you need to show your form action. Even if you set it via javascript,  the real form action would be displayed in the js file. Your requirements doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. I wonder what you are trying to achieve with this?

Anyway kind of question has already been answered here

[Hide form action url in post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255014/hide-form-action-url-in-post-method)

To obfuscate action url you could use some javascript to set attribute only on submit. Here you can see a dumb example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gprygB

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(this).attr("action", "realAction");
});


<form action="fakeAction">
  <input type="submit" />  
</form>
```

Thanks to this you could also use some crypt/uglify library to hide the realAction inside js file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is point of hiding the action of the form in case you are thinking in security point of view also this doesnt make any sense you need to protect your backend in this case
Anyways if you want to do nothing when the form is submitted then
`$(form).click(function(e){ 
  E.preventDefault();
Return false;
});`
In case you want to hide it
`$(form).attr("action", " " );`
Add this in `window.ready()`
Hope it will work