# hide an HTML form action url from the page source

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible I hide an HTML form action url from user? I mean that user can't see it on the page source code.

I found [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255014/hide-form-action-url-in-post-method) , but in this way user can find that action from the page source!

Comment: Click F12, click network tab. Whatever you choose to obfuscate the form action will be shown in the network tab on submit

Comment: The URL has to exist in the page source or your page will not know where to go. As said in the link you found, you can obfuscate where that URL is, but it has to be there somewhere. You need to protect your URLs on the server-side.

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: still no, but your server side business logic validation and security infrastructure should be in place to reduce the risk of attack.

Comment: "Security" by obscurity is never the answer to anything.

Answer (score 0):

In principle this is impossible, because the browser needs to know how to handle the form, and anything the browser knows, the user can know. Perhaps if you give more details about what it is you're trying to do, there is another solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27395840)

Comment: The question is "Is it possible I hide an HTML form action url from user?" I said "In principle this is impossible". I provided a DIRECT answer to the question.

Comment: The post answers the question and even gives a reason for its answer, so it's fine in my opinion.